# MaterialUI - How can I have 2 different selectfield with same MenuItem but it will select differently?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 SelectField and I want it to function as 2 different SelectField. My code is working but when I click on the 1st SelectField, the 2nd SelectField will also choose the same MenuItem as the 1st one.

How can I change it as 2 different SelectField?

```
    <SelectField value={this.state.selectedBrandings} onChange={this.onBrandingsChange} id={t}>
        {_.map(this.state.brandings, (b) => {
          return <MenuItem value={b.name} primaryText={b.name} key={b.id}/>;
        })}
    </SelectField>

<SelectField value={this.state.selectedBrandings} onChange={this.onBrandingsChange} id={t}>
        {_.map(this.state.brandings, (b) => {
          return <MenuItem value={b.name} primaryText={b.name} key={b.id}/>;
        })}
    </SelectField>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working on this codes
the function below:

```
onBrandingsChange = (event, index, value) => {
    var newBrandings = this.state.selectedOrder;
    newBrandings.prints.printMethod.push(value)
    this.setState({selectedOrder: newBrandings});
  }
```

upon render

```
{_.map(this.state.test, (t, id) => {
    <SelectField value={this.state.selectedOrder.prints.printMethod[id]} onChange={this.onBrandingsChange}>
        {_.map(this.state.brandings, (b) => {
          return <MenuItem value={b.name} primaryText={b.name} key={b.id}/>;
        })}
    </SelectField>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect two selectfields to work differently if they are getting value from the same state and updating the same state in onChange. You should have two different states for them.